# a datable using ajax json in PHP Codeigniter , my custom filter button is not working

Tags: php, ajax, datatable, codeigniter-3

[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ee4Ot.png)Image

this is the view of my table , there's a product filter option on the top that i want to run as per this sql query

SELECT * FROM `warehouses_products` WHERE expiry < SYSDATE() OR quantity < 15;

> now can u please tell me the code i have to code in view , model and
> controller to run this filter button

**this is my view.php**

```
<div class="container">
       
        <br>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title" >Product Filter : </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
            <form  id="filter" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('product/inStock');?>">
                <div class="form-group" class="col-md-3">

                   
                    <label for="product">Product</label>
                    <select class="form-control select2" id="filter" name="filter"  style="width: 30%;">
                      <option  value="">Select</option>
                      <option name="quantity" id="quantity" > Low Quantity </option>
                      <option name="expiry" id="expiry" > Expired  </option>
                     
                     
                    </select>
                    
                  </div>
                    
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="LastName" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <button type="button" id="filter" class="btn btn-primary">Filter</button>
                            <button type="button" id="btn-reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**this is my model.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Customers_model extends CI_Model {

    var $table = 'warehouses_products';
    var $column_order = array(null, 'product_id','warehouse_id','batch','expiry','quantity','modified_date','created_date'); //set column field database for datatable orderable
    var $column_search = array('product_id','warehouse_id','batch','expiry','quantity','modified_date','created_date'); //set column field database for datatable searchable 
    var $order = array('id' => 'asc'); // default order 

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

   

    private function _get_datatables_query()
    {
        
        $this->db->from($this->table);

        $i = 0;
    
        foreach ($this->column_search as $item) // loop column 
        {
            if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
            {
                
                if($i===0) // first loop
                {
                    $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                    $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }

                if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                    $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
            }
            $i++;
        }
        
        if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
        {
            $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
        } 
        else if(isset($this->order))
        {
            $order = $this->order;
            $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
        }
    }

    function get_datatables()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        if($_POST['length'] != -1)
        $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
    

     

    function count_filtered()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }

    public function count_all()
    {
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }

}
```

**this is my controler.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Customers extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('customers_model','warehouses_products');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('inStock_view');
    }
     
    function expiry(){
    $expiry = $this->input->GET('expiry');
    $data['search'] = $this->Voucher_m->check_expiry($expiry);
    $this->load->view('/VENDOR/'.country_code.'/Voucher',$data);
}  
        
    public function ajax_list()
    {
        $list = $this->warehouses_products->get_datatables();
        $data = array();
        $no = $_POST['start'];
        foreach ($list as $warehouses_products) {
            $no++;
            $row = array();
            $row[] = $no;
            $row[] = $warehouses_products->product_id;
            $row[] = $warehouses_products->warehouse_id;
            $row[] = $warehouses_products->batch;
            $row[] = $warehouses_products->expiry;
            $row[] = $warehouses_products->quantity;
            $row[] = $warehouses_products->modified_date;
            $row[] = $warehouses_products->created_date;
            
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        $output = array(
                        "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                        "recordsTotal" => $this->warehouses_products->count_all(),
                        "recordsFiltered" => $this->warehouses_products->count_filtered(),
                        "data" => $data,
                );
        //output to json format
        echo json_encode($output);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using a JSON response to use as a source for jQuery DataTables plugin? The question is rather ambiguous; please clarify your objective more.

Comment: Yes, I'm using JSON

Answer (score 0):

in your view file do something like this

```
    var dropdownValue=$('#yourdropdownid').val();
var table =$('#myTable').DataTable({
        pageLength: 10,
        paging:true,
        //autoWidth: false,
        responsive: true,
        dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
        buttons: [
            {extend: 'excel', title: 'ExampleFile', className: 'btn btn-primary btn-xs'},
            {extend: 'pdf', title: 'ExampleFile', className: 'btn btn-warning btn-xs'},
            {extend: 'print',
                customize: function (win){
                    $(win.document.body).addClass('white-bg');
                    $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');

                    $(win.document.body).find('table')
                        .addClass('compact')
                        .css('font-size', 'inherit');
                },
                className: 'btn btn-success btn-xs'
            }
        ],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                "targets": 0,
                "width": "15%",
                "searchable": false, "orderable": false, "visible": true
            },
            {
                "targets": 1,
                "searchable": false, "orderable": false, "visible": false
            },
            {
                "targets": 2,
                "width": "15%",
                "searchable": false, "orderable": false, "visible": true
            },
            {
                "targets": 3,
                "searchable": false, "orderable": false, "visible": false
            },
            {
                "targets": 4,
                "searchable": false, "orderable": false, "visible": false
            },

        ],
        order: [[ 2, 'asc' ]],
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url:baseUrl+"allsubject",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { dropdownValue:dropdownValue },
            complete: function(response) {
                //console.log(response.responseJSON.data);
            }
        },
        columns: [
            { data: "action" },
            { data: "id" },
            { data: "subject_name" },
            { data: "entry_by" },
            { data: "entry_date" },
        ],

    });
```

then you can store "dropdownValue" in a variable in controller using $_POST['dropdownValue'] and can be used in model in where clause...

Answer (score 0):

some changes like data fetching ny id instead by declaring variable in model then print by ajax in array format

view code like

````
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="product">Product</label>
                    <select class="form-control select2" id="filter" name="filter" style="width: 100%;">
                      <option  value="">Select</option>
                      <option name="lowQty" id="lowQty" <?php if($filter == "Low Quantity" && !empty($filter)){echo "selected";} ?>> Low Quantity </option>
                      <option name="expired" id="expired" <?php if($filter == "Expired" && !empty($filter)){echo "selected";} ?>> Expired </option>
                    </select>
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="warehouse">Search</label> <br />
                    <input type = "search" name="search" id = "search" value ="<?php if(!empty($search)){echo $search;} ?>" class = "form-control input-sm"> </input>
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="box-footer">
                    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="submit" name="submit" value="search">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary-info" name="submit">Submit</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

<!-- this is the second section-->
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title">List </h3>
              
            </div></form>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
              <table id="index" class="table table-bordered table-striped ">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th> No </th>
                  <th>Product</th>
                  <th>Quantity</th>
                  <th>Expiry</th>
                  <th>Location</th>
                  
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  
                    <?php 
                        $no = 0;
                        foreach ($record as $record) {
                            $id= $record->product_id;

                      ?>
                      <tr>
                        <td><?php echo ++$no; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $record->product_id; ?> </td>
                        <td><?php echo $record->quantity; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $record->expiry; ?></td>
                      </tr>
                      <?php
                        }
                      ?>
                  </tbody>```


    model file
````

````
public function inStockFilter($filter = '',$search = ''){
    ///same for expiry need to write 
    $this->db->select('WP.product_id,WP.quantity,WP.expiry,W.warehouse_name,P.name');
    $this->db->from('warehouses_products AS WP');
    $this->db->join('warehouse as W','W.warehouse_id = WP.warehouse_id');
    $this->db->join('products as P','P.product_id = WP.product_id');

    if(!empty($filter)){
        if($filter == "Expired"){
            $this->db->where('WP.expiry <=',date("Y-m-d"));
            $this->db->order_by('WP.expiry',"DESC");
        }
        if($filter == "Low Quantity"){
            $this->db->where('P.quantity <','100');
        }
    }

    if(!empty($search)){
        $this->db->like('P.product_id', $filter);   
    }

    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    return $query->result();
    return false;```



control file
````

```
    {
        $filter = "";
        $search = "";
        if(!empty($this->input->post('filter'))){
            $filter = $this->input->post('filter');
            $data['filter'] = $filter;
        }
        if(!empty($this->input->post('search'))){
            $search = $this->input->post('search');
            $data['search'] = $search;
        }

        $data['record'] = $this->product_model->inStockFilter($filter, $search);

        $this->load->view('product/instock',$data);
    }
```